# Simultaneously write and upload a file

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using google apis nodejs client for uploading files to Google Drive.

Currently, I pass a readable stream of file for uploading which was downloaded from another server via a write stream.

But accidentally I started uploading to Drive before its completely written by its write stream. Surprisingly the uploaded succeeded.

Now, I want to know that is this accidental or normal ?

Can I pass a readable stream whose writable stream is still writing to it ?

Is this a good practice ?